# befor_filter authorize depend on controller_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authorization, roles

in my project i use devise

but i want if the user is admin he can enter to all controllers
but if the user is regular user he can enter to specific controllers

this is my code:

```
 before_filter :authorize!
def authorize!
      unless current_admin.is_admin?
        flash[:alert] = "unauthorized access"
        redirect_to root_path   
      end
    end
```

how can i get the controller name in the authorize method
for example if the controller name is "dashboard" or "stations" the regular user can see the data.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

controller name is available in `params[:controller]` and action in `params[:action]`

However I would recommend adding a `AdminController.rb` file

```
 #controllers/admin_controller.rb
 class AdminController < ApplicationController::Base
    before_filter :authorize!
    def authorize!
      unless current_user.is_admin?
        flash[:alert] = "unauthorized access"
        redirect_to root_path   
      end
    end    
 end
```

and inheriting all the controllers that only admin can access like below

```
# controllers/admin_only_controller
class AdminOnlyController < AdminController
end
```

This way you can manage normal user controllers and admin controllers separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `controller_name`

If you want to get action name - use `action_name`

Answer (score 0):

actually both answers are ok

the params[:controller] is better because of its contains also the namespace.

this is my final code. 
any ideas for write better this peace of code is welcome

```
def authorize!
    unless current_admin.is_admin?  
        case current_admin.type
            when :station_admin
                station_admin_allows_controllers = ["radio/stations","radio/dashboard"]
                unless station_admin_allows_controllers.include?(params[:controller])
                    flash[:alert] = "unauthorized access"
                    redirect_to root_path   
                end
            end
    end
  end
```